# How do I draw pictorial representation of a code dissection such as this one?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, smartdiagram

I am doing some reverse engineering, which means I will dig into assembly and explain sections of code next to the code in a diagram. An example of this approach is shown below.

[image]

[image]

Any one of the two styles above would do. Or something similar if available in LaTex package. Easier it is, the better.

Which package can I use in `LaTex` that will allow me to do this? Is it `Tikz`? Can I use `smartdiagram`? Can someone point me to a resource or sample code for this?

Comment: I tried to include a screen shot of one of the sources. But apparently I don't have enough skill to do that on my smartphone. Please help and edit the question again.

Comment: included figures as requested

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to directly link external documents here. They can be dangerous or the link can be broken in the future.

Comment: got it, thanks. I've removed all external links and replaced them with images.

Comment: may be you can try with `tcolorbox` package

Comment: There's an extension to the `tikzmark` TikZ library that integrates it with the `listings` package, initiated by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79787/86 (but see the package documentation for how to use it).