# Use arrows to point to specific blocks of code and assign background colors to keywords

Tags: listings, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

How do I get background colors assigned to certain words and punctuation marks? I want it like in the following picture:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\tikzmark#1{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[yshift=2pt](#1){};}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    escapeinside={*}{*},
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\newcommand\PlaceText[3]{%
\begin{textblock*}{10in}(#1,#2)  %% change width of box from 10in as you wish
#3
\end{textblock*}
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
# Here is the function:
def hello():*\tikzmark{A}*
    print("Hello together!")

# Main:
hello() *\tikzmark{B}*
hello() *\tikzmark{C}*
hello() *\tikzmark{D}*
\end{lstlisting}
\tikzset{Empharrow/.style={dashed,red,thick,->,arrows={-Triangle[width=3pt]}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[Empharrow](D)--+(7cm,0)|-(A);
\draw[Empharrow](C)--+(6cm,0)|-(A);
\draw[Empharrow](B)--+(5.5cm,0)|-(A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\PlaceText{100mm}{60mm}{The \texttt{hello()} function is called here}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Is there a more elegant way? Nonetheless, my main concern is the background color of certain words in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for this:

[image: use arrows to point to code]

In this case, you just have to edit your `tikzpicture` like the following, and delete your `PlaceText` line.

Everything else is OK.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[Empharrow](D)--+(7cm,0)|-(A.north east)node[pos=0.25,right,text width=4cm]{The \texttt{hello()} function\\is called here};
\draw[Empharrow](C)--+(6cm,0)|-(A);
\draw[Empharrow](B)--+(5.5cm,0)|-(A.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I get background colors assigned to certain words and punctuation marks?

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. It was about background colours. I'll try and add this tomorrow. It can be done with `tikzmark` library if you don't want to automatize it. Otherwise, you'll have to find a way to add backgrounds on `listings`, which I don't know how to do... yet.

Comment: I did some research and only found [this article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79762/automatic-background-coloring-in-listings-using-tikzmark) explaining how to make `tikzmark` and `listings` libraries work together, but it's not possible to colour *some* words this way. Not sure this is the best way to do this. Maybe [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey) could give some help on that.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey Do you have an idea?